# Can't use ok google anymore

Tags: google, google-maps

my problem here started about 2 months ago. i searched a lot for an answer before asking for help here. but didn't find anything.
i'm from Iran. i used to be able to use google now and its cards before. but after my phone's crash, i gave it back to the company i bought it from. they reinstalled the ROM and fixed it. after that, i couldn't use google services anymore and not even able to save offline map in google maps !
every time i try to use it, it says "This account is not eligible to use google now"

do you guys have any idea for fixing it ?!
i repeat, I was able to use it before.

my device: HTC ONE E8

Tnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the company has signed in on Android using another Google account different from yours. Follow the instructions [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/4570255) to add an account (so you enter the account you have always used on your phone) and switch it.

Comment: i've already logged into my own google accounts ( i have 2 accounts ). but it says the message i mentioned before.

Comment: i also have another android phone which is rooted. right now, i tried to log into my google account on it to make it work on the other device which is rooted. i did every step like others do (using market unlocker and etc.). but it didn't work on that one too. so the problem is way deeper than i estimated.